# Google Chrome crashes when attempting to access Desktop Bookmarks (Asus Nexus 7)

Tags: nexus-7, chrome-for-android

Steps to reproduce:

- launch Google Chrome browser and open new tab
- touch bookmarks option on bottom menu
- select Desktop Bookmarks

This causes Google Chrome to crash, resulting in:

> *"Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this web page. To continue, reload or go to another page"*

Screenshot:

[image]

Debug output:

http://pastebin.com/CqypRRbv

I have tried the following actions, which have been unsuccessful:

- disable/enable Chrome Sync
- restore tablet

Does anyone else have this issue or this is this an isolated problem?

Comment: works for me :-(

Comment: Works for me, too. Could you probably get us a LogCat? Heres how: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/how-can-i-get-a-logcat