# How can I get a LogCat?

Tags: logging, debug

Sometimes I get asked for a LogCat.

**What is this?** 
**What is it supposed to do?** 
**How can I get it?**

Comment: Hmm. Possible. I searched for it, but don't found something similar. ;)

Answer (score 8):

**What is a LogCat?** 
A "LogCat" is for debugging applications / Android system. When applications / Android crash the output the "explanation" for the crash, the Exception Stacktrace, to a Log. This log can be saved and help developers to fix the crash.

**What is it supposed to do?** 
It will help to solve your questions, if your asked for a LogCat it is always useful.

**How can I get a LogCat?** 
This isn't hard.

*Prerequisites:* 
Linux, Windows or Mac 
USB cable for your device 
Android Device

*Instructions:*

1. Install your device driver for using adb. Everything you need will you find [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)
2. Download adb executable for your OS (Download: [Windows](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2843058/logcattut/adb.exe) | [Linux](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2843058/logcattut/adb) | Mac). Paste it somewhere.
3. Connect your android device.
4. Verify if "Settings > Developer options > USB debugging" is checked, if not, simply check it.
5. Open a command promt (windows) or terminal (linux / mac). How to do it: On Windows: windows + r > enter "cmd" (without quotes) > click enter | On Linux: You don't know how to open a terminal? LOL | On Mac: Type `Terminal` into Spotlight and open it
6. CD to the directory where the adb executable is located. On Windows: Go to the directory where you downloaded the adb executable, Shift+Right Click and select "Open Console" (or similar) | On Linux / Mac: Rightclick in the directory and select "Open Terminal here" (or simply CD into the directory)
7. Type in your cmd/terminal: `adb devices` to verify your device is properly connected.
8. If your device is properly selected, type in `adb logcat` to show the mighty and magic logcat aka stacktrace.
9. Reproduce your error (or whatever) on your device.
10. Right after, paste the whole cmd / terminal window into a paste-service like http://pastebin.com/ and send it to us.

Comment: Or you could just use an app like aLogCat and easily share the resultant log file via email, messenger, upload to dropbox etc.

Comment: Nope, not possible with JellyBean. The API changed, you only can read the LogCat from your own app.

Comment: aLogCat is being updated. An alternative called CatLog also works but it needs root access for JB devices.