# What is the content of data/misc/wifi/softap.conf?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, file-system

I was going through a question about how to find a saved password in a rooted phone and while doing this I found a file in `data/misc/wifi/softap.conf`. What is the content of this file?

Comment: please consider posting a comment before downvoting....(I am not against downvoting but i should know the reason so that i will not repeat the mistake if any).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `.conf` file is usually readable by any text file reader as long as permissions are correct.

The said file contains SSID and password of your portable Wi-Fi hotspot. E.g.:

```
Android.SE  #$#$ANDROID
```

where `Android.SE` is the SSID which other users would see when trying to locate Wi-Fi network and `#$#$ANDROID` is the password they need to enter to connect to your hotspot.

As for the name is concerned, I never researched for it because I know `ap` → Access point, and I've seen `softap` term in logcat's output when enabling hotspot.

There are other ways to see the content of this file. In my Android 4.2.1, I can do:

```
adb shell su -c 'service call wifi 30'
```

As for the Android 5.0 (CM12), it would be:

```
adb shell service call wifi 36
```

The output isn't very human-friendly but it's not unreadable, and you can easily see SSID and password of hotspot.

**Edit**: For those who might wonder what those `adb shell ..` commands actually does in bits and pieces, here is a missing piece:

- `adb shell`: you get a remote shell (access to device)
- `su`: to attain root privileges, use if only necessary; `-c`: is to pass the following command which would  be executed with root privileges
- `service`: it allows you to read and manipulate services running in your system. Enter `adb shell service list` to see a list of running ones, and `adb shell service` to see the command's usage.
- `call connectivity`: to call a particular service (`connectivity` here). Name of services can be found using `service list`.
- `36` is the number assigned to a function of the connectivity service amongst many of it, which we're calling here. You can also pass an integer or a string to the function like `adb shell service call connectivity 36 i32 1`, but it would take effect only if the function has provision to accept such value. Take a look [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/net/IConnectivityManager.java#) to see such functions.

Comment: Correct! it consists of SSID and password(I couldn't recognize it). Bieng a noob in android development i would like to know about "logcat" and the commandline thing "adb shell ....". By the way thankyou for your response.

Comment: @Jasser A quick note: This site is for end-users only, which means all development/programming questions would be off-topic. That said, "logcat" and "adb" is for end-users too, so try [How can I get a LogCat?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33216/96277), and as for `adb shell`: it opens a remote shell on your PC where you can send commands to Android device. More Q/A only on a new question please. :) And do search since your question might be asked before.