# Is my phone hardware damaged?

Tags: hardware, crashes, crash-reports

Ocassionally when I use my phone, it crashes.

## EDIT:

*From analysing the pictures posted, we can conclude that the OP has an Asus Zenfone 2 (probably ZE551ML) running Lollipop 5.0 LRX21V.*

This is very annoying if I play Clash of Clans and stuff. Imagine, in the middle of a war and then crash!

Fortunately I knew a way to get the system log.

I installed Airdrop Detector. It crashes on any phone. When it crashes it gives me an option to report the crash. I wonder if there is another way to get that.

Here are some of the screen shots.

<sub>Click images to enlarge</sub>

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

It says fatal signal hardware test.

The store I bought the phone from has a history of problems with the devices I bought from them. The first phone I bought had a Chinese ROM in it. The second phone has these constant ads. They managed to fix that. However, the original problem, namely that apps often crash is still there.

There are some error that complains about OpenGL:

<sub>Click images to enlarge</sub>

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Please help me verify if the phone is hardware damaged or not.

I found a bug and I post the video on youtube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzAuaIw4RT0

Comment: Some OEMs offer hardware testing option under stock recovery? Did you check  to see if you have such option, by booting into your stock recovery? See [tag:recovery], if needed.

Comment: Please provide us with information about your device, such as make, model, Android version, etc. Also, what you need is to run `adb logcat`. I can assume that you have ADB set up, if you don't then refer here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/33216/how-can-i-get-a-logcat

Comment: The first error indicates a segment fault probably, as the process was forcefully aborted. That might indicate a fault with RAM, but only as an extreme case. You should try a [tag:factory-reset] to see if that helps. The second, I'm not really sure. Maybe the app needs an OpenGL version higher than that supplied by the OEM? Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6

Comment: It'z zenfone 2. I already updated the OS to the latest version.

Comment: Also, a phone uses an eMMC or NAND flash for storage, not a hard drive.

Comment: I should ask at zenfone forum

Comment: I'm not an authority of smart phone providers, but it looks like you're getting scammed. I would buy a smart phone from a more trustworthy store - perhaps Walmart or Target. I'm not sure how to fix your phone's problem, though.

Comment: I suspected I've been scammed too. It seems that the store sell refurbished product and claim it's new. They replaced the phone once. Both phone have obvious problems.

Comment: Currently I can play clash of clans without problems. No more problem it seems. I am just too afraid to change it into my main phone.

Comment: Can anyone see the video?

Answer (score 3):

A few things to note:

<sub>Answer compiled from comments</sub>

1. A SIGABRT signal/error generally indicates that the system forcefully stopped a process from executing, via the syscall `abort()`. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413166/when-does-a-process-get-sigabrt-signal-6) SO question.
2. OpenGL ES libraries not found: It could be that your OEM does not or has not provided the OpenGL ES libraries which this app requires or has provided them in a non-standard location(usually OpenGL ES 3.0 is not provided on some devices (see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) Android developer's resource), and library locations can change with kernel versions, an app relying on Kitkat's library location may not work on Lollipop).
3. Crashes can be due to a number of issues, usually due to battery power issues or overheating, although either of these may not be immediately apparent.

You could try the following:

1. A [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). This should help with any problems that are due to user misconfigurations.
2. You could test (log) the temperature of your device with a suitable app such as [CPU-Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z&hl=en) or [3C Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.at.free&hl=en) until you get a crash. If the device temperature goes above 70 degrees Celsius, overheating could be a cause of this behaviour.
3. Similarly, you could also check the battery output current using CPU-Z, I am not exactly sure but from personal experience I can say that a battery draw voltage of less than 2000 mV at 40% to 60% charge level can lead to power issues and crashes. (Thanks to my old Micromax Canvas Magnus, which had a similar issue which I so diagnosed, and a battery replacement fixed it).
4. As you yourself suggested, checking out customer service and user forums for the product might be a good idea.
5. Also, as @Firelord suggested, you should check if your recovery offers some hardware-testing facilities, which some manufacturers provide.

Comment: For many/most non-deterministic hardware problems, it's nigh on impossible to have a "sure-fire" way to diagnose it.